# Property "Qty" does not have accessor method "getQty" in class Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface

Tags: magento2.3, api, stock

I get this error:

> [2022-03-24 11:32:10] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-623c56baea1fe;
> Message: Property "Qty" does not have accessor method "getQty" in
> class "Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface".
> {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID:
> webapi-623c56baea1fe; Message: Property "Qty" does not have accessor
> method "getQty" in class
> "Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface". at
> /domains/dev.vapestore.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208,
> LogicException(code: 0): Property "Qty" does not have accessor
> method "getQty" in class
> "Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface". at
> /domains/dev.vapestore.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/NameFinder.php:100)"}
> []

When trying to update the stock qty of a product via API.

The request using Postman:

```
POST: /index.php/rest/all/V1/inventory/source-items
body: 
{
  "sourceItems": [{
    "sku": "PE-GR-03",
    "source_code": "02",
    "qty": 5,
    "status": 1
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...

The property name for quantity should be "quantity" not "qty".

That works:

```
POST: /index.php/rest/all/V1/inventory/source-items
body: 
{
  "sourceItems": [{
    "sku": "PE-GR-03",
    "source_code": "02",
    "quantity": 5,
    "status": 1
  }]
}
```